# Turn Weighted Numbers into Multiple Histograms

Tags: python, csv, random, histogram

I am using the below code to create a weighted list of random numbers within a range.

```
import csv
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

itemsList = []

rnd_numbs = csv.writer(open("rnd_numbs.csv", "wb"))
rnd_numbs.writerow(['number'])

items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
probabilities= [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4]
prob = sum(probabilities) 
print prob
c = (1.0)/prob 
probabilities = map(lambda x: c*x, probabilities)
print probabilities

ml = max(probabilities, key=lambda x: len(str(x)) - str(x).find('.'))
ml = len(str(ml)) - str(ml).find('.') -1
amounts = [ int(x*(10**ml)) for x in probabilities]
itemsList = list()
for i in range(0, len(items)): 
  itemsList += items[i:i+1]*amounts[i]
for item in itemsList:
    rnd_numbs.writerow([item])
```

What I would like to do is (a) list these numbers randomly down the csv column, not sure why they are coming out pre-sorted, (b) list the numbers down the comumn instead of as one entry, and (c) create and save multiple histrograms at defined intervals, such as the first 100 numbers, then first 250 numbers, then first 500 numbers, ... to the end

For (c) I would like to create multiple pictures such as this for various cutoffs of the data list.

[image: Histogram Example]

Attempt at histogram

```
x = itemsList[0:20]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# 100 is the number of bins
ax.hist(x, 10, normed=1, facecolor='green', alpha=0.75)

ax.set_xlim(0, 5)
ax.set_ylim(0, 500)
ax.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: not sure what you mean by c, can you give an example?

Comment: where does the random part come from?

Comment: @cmd I am trying to take the weighting scheme to produce numbers at each time period and then see what the distribution looks like within certain rolling time intervals. It is going to be used as a teaching tool to show how the central limit theorem and consistency work. The online tools for this are bloody boring so I was attempting to make my own.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That was a lapse in thinking, fixed what I meant in the title. Random comes in only in the output

Comment: I think it would help if you gave an example of what you would like this to look like at the end.

Comment: @CJ12, so you want a random list of numbers up to 500  and to plot a hist for the first first 100 then go back to start and plot 250 etc..?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I want to use the list that results from the shuffle and then plot the hist for the first 100 then go back to and and 250, etc. I would like to play with the end points as custom as possible (they might not be even breaks). For example, I may go 0-20, 0-100, 0-1000

Comment: @CJ12, it is easy  to step through in different step ranges, the part I am unclear over is, are the 100,250,500 coming from different ranges of the items and probabilities lists or from repeatedly looping over using the same five getting randomness from shuffling the items list?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham After the initial shuffle they are coming from the same item list

Comment: @CJ12, to make this clear, a list of 500 numbers, plot the distribution for the first 100 numbers in the list, then 250 and finally all  500?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That is 100% correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the third part of your question, take a look at [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org) (and [`numpy.loadtxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) for reading your data). There are many [examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/index.html) to help you learn the basics, as well as advanced features. Here's a quick example of plotting a histogram of a random normal distribution:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.randn(10000)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# 100 is the number of bins
n = ax.hist(x, 100, facecolor='green', alpha=0.75)

# n[0] is the array of bin heights,
# n[1] is the array of bin edges
xmin = min(n[1]) * 1.1
xmax = max(n[1]) * 1.1
ymax = max(n[0]) * 1.1

ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
ax.set_ylim(0, ymax)
ax.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

which gives you a nice image:

[image: Matplotlib histogram example]

You can make loops to generate multiple images using different ranges of your data, and save the generated figures in a number of formats, with or without previewing them first.

Comment: Besides taking over 45 minutes to get `numpy` and `matlibplot` to work (and they finally do). I cannot get even one of my graphs to populate. I took some examples and your code and did what is now edited into my question.

Comment: @CJ12 - what platform are you using? If it's Windows, check out Christoph Gohlke's [Python Extension Packages for Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) repository of prepackaged Python modules for scientific computing. You can get an [MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl)-enhanced [version of `NumPy`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy), [`matplotlib`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib), and all of its dependencies, which are listed right there. On OS X, I use MacPorts, and there should be packages available on most Linux distros.

Comment: @CJ12 - I'm not quite sure what your issue is with plotting. Does a plot window appear, and is just missing the graph, or does it not even appear? How are you running your script - command line or through an editor/IDE? Do you get any error messages? Could you get any of the `matplotlib` [example files](http://matplotlib.org/examples/index.html) to run successfully?

Comment: The plot window appears without the graph. I could get examples to run. All I am trying to do (see my question) is plot the first 20 elements from `itemList`. I am running from command line

Comment: @CJ12 does it work if you remove `normed=1` from the call to `ax.hist()`? Other than that, the only thing I can think of is that some part of `numpy` or `matplotlib` is failing silently. How did you install (and eventually get to work) the modules?

Comment: @CJ12 also, how do you generate `itemsList`? Can you give me an example of the first, say, 5 items? Just add the line `print(itemsList[0:5])` to your code right after you assign the first 20 values to `x`.

Comment: The way `itemList` is generated is in the code at the top of my question. The result of `print(itemsList[0:5])` is `[1, 3, 5, 5, 4]`

Comment: It seems that it is not working because I set the ylimit too high. It is returning probabilities for the `ax.set_ylim` instead of frequencies. How do I make this change?

Comment: I think a combination of removing `normed=1` (check [the docs](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) on it) and using `ax.set_ylim(0, max(x)+max(x)*0.1)` to dynamically size your chart based on the data should do the trick. I hope :)

Comment: @CJ12 I just updated the code and image to reflect our discussion, and also to correct a minor error I made in calculating `ylim`. You should now be able to adapt it directly to your situation by just changing the number of bins, and setting the X and Y axes, if you want them different from 110% of the max/min.